# ComboBox is not populated if the message box is popped up in the selectionchanged event in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a checkbox in my WPF application. when selection change of the `ComboBox` should display a modal window. but the selected item is not reflected in the `ComboBox`. I googled and found the solution using Dispatched. But is there any other way to do that?

I referred the [MessageBox pops up behind ComboBox drop down list, obscuring content in MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126911/messagebox-pops-up-behind-combobox-drop-down-list-obscuring-content-in-messageb)
for the dispatcher.

Comment: @Tanya: What solution did you find using the Dispatcher?  And is there any other way to do what?  You've not clearly described the problem you're having, so it's not an easy question to answer.

Comment: @Tanya, you misspelled popped, I'll fix it for you

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed">
            <sys:String>A</sys:String>
            <sys:String>B</sys:String>
            <sys:String>C</sys:String>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((sender as Selector).SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```